# how did i get this sprite sheet work on "jsfiddle"?

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

i am pasting this code on "jsfiddle" but somehow the animation sprite sheet did not run ,what the problem ?

**Website :** [thecave.info](http://www.thecave.info/2d-sprite-animation-tutorial/)

Comment: You don't think a link to said fiddle might be in order?

Comment: have you changed the Image Url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better not to use string as parameter for setInterval

But there are no troubles in code ( you should fix sprite path to absolute )

```
_http://jsfiddle.net/bpu4eh34/
```